# Cronjob not working properly on debian

Tags: php, debian, cron, cron.daily

I'm trying to run a PHP script everyday at midnight, so my cron has the following entry

```
@daily /usr/bin/php /websites/xxz/misc/wU5HaFre.php
```

`/websites/xxz/misc/wU5HaFre.php` has 755 rights, so it's executable.

`which php` provides `/usr/bin/php`, `whereis php provides`

```
php: /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/X11/php /usr/share/php /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz
```

So what's wrong? It just doesn't execute.

Comment: What does syslog say when CRON is ran?

Comment: @mako_reactor what do you mean?

Comment: When a cron job is ran, the log is written to `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/messages`. Look in the log for the cron log: it would looks somthing like:

`22 12:17:01 hostname CRON[426] Message`

Comment: `Feb 22 19:15:01 rnd-cust2 /USR/SBIN/CRON[24164]: (www-data) CMD (/usr/bin/php /websites/xxz/misc/wU5HaFre.php)` seems to pop out pretty often. @mako_reactor

Answer (score 0):

It seems www-data is trying to run the script (is this what you want?) Run:

`sudo -u www-data /usr/bin/php /websites/xxz/misc/wU5HaFre.php`

in terminal and see what the output is, or if the script works.

Comment: `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/2010052          5/suhosin.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/suhosin.so: cannot open shared object fil          e: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Could not open input file: /websites/xxz/misc/wU5HaFre.php`

Comment: I changed php to php5 and things started running, but it produces this error: `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/2010052        5/suhosin.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/suhosin.so: cannot open shared object fil        e: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
`

Comment: What linux distro are you using? Did you install/compile php5-suhosin?

Comment: Like I said in the title, Debian. Squeeze to be accurate. How do I install/compile php5-suhosin as apt-get install php5-suhosin gives `Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-suhosin : Depends: phpapi-20090626
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`?

Comment: And also: `apt-get install phpapi-20090626
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package phpapi-20090626 is a virtual package provided by:
  php5-cli 5.3.3-7+squeeze14 [Not candidate version]
  php5-cgi 5.3.3-7+squeeze14 [Not candidate version]
  libapache2-mod-php5filter 5.3.3-7+squeeze14 [Not candidate version]
  libapache2-mod-php5 5.3.3-7+squeeze14 [Not candidate version]

E: Package 'phpapi-20090626' has no installation candidate
`

Comment: You may need to compile php5 from source and add Suhosin in the configuration. Seems your apt repos are not liking php5-suhosin...

Comment: And how I'm supposed to do that? I've never compiled anything.

Comment: www.osmialowski.co.uk/compile-php-5-3-11-on-debian-squeeze